# SharePoint Content Type with document template from different site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I need to store document templates in a global site collection and reuse it in the content type across multiple site collections. When I try to create a document from the template it gives this error:

> Failed to create file

Any idea why this happens?

Note: I don't want to use Content Type hub because of its other limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you save a document template of a content type in a site collection library, and upload to a library in another site collection?

If so, per my test, I can use the document template in another site collection library.

How do you store and reuse the document template? Try to edit the template in office client and save as a template file in local location and upload it to the relevant content type, then check if the issue exists.

Comment: Yes, I want to store all my document templates in one central site collection library and reuse them in other site collections. The content types in other site collections should refer the template from central library. I don't want to store it locally in each site collection. The problem is I can't create a file when the template is stored in a different site site collection. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question and before I go into bow I solved it, I figured I would find out first if you got it sorted out.